# How to eagerly fetch data in JPA and Hibernate to use outside of session?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm new to Hibernate and JPA, but cannot seem to get this to work.

These models are persisted, where the `EntityHistory` has a set of linked changes in the `EntityHistoryChange` table:

```
@Table
@RooJavaBean
@RooJpaActiveRecord
public class EntityHistory {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "history")
    private Set<EntityHistoryChange> changes = new HashSet<>();
}


@Table
@AssociationOverride(name="history", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name ="entityHistoryId"))
@RooJavaBean
@RooJpaActiveRecord
public class EntityHistoryChange {

    @Lob
    @Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.TextType")
    private String change;
}
```

Then I need to access this data all at once to serialize it out for a scheduled export.

I have a service with a scheduled job:

```
// Trying to fetch entire object so can use it outside of session
@Service
public class ScheduledExecutor {

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 05 0 * * ?")
    public void extractHistory() {      
        long lastId = 12345l;
        List<EntityHistory> history = findHistoriesWithIdGreater(lastId);

        for(EntityHistoryChange change : history.get(6).getChanges()){
            logger.info("                    change is: " + change.getChange());
        }
    }

    public static List<EntityHistory> findHistoriesWithIdGreater(Long lastId) {
        TypedQuery<EntityHistory> query = entityManager().createQuery(
                "select a from EntityHistory a join fetch a.changes c where a.id > :lastId order by a.id",
                EntityHistory.class);

        query.setParameter("lastId", lastId);
        return query.getResultList();
    }
}
```

But when it runs, I keep getting this error:

`org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: Unable to perform requested lazy initialization [com.company.model.EntityHistory.changes] - no session and settings disallow loading outside the Session`

I thought that by putting the `join fetch` in the JPQL query, it should eagerly grab all the data in that join.

Comment: How do the generated SQL statements look like?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I'm not sure.  How can I turn those on to see?  Based on the feedback from Andronicus, it sounds like the 'fetch' command in the JPQL is treated as a hint by hibernate, and it's not necessarily enforced.  In any event, I did find a solution that works for my purposes which I'll update in a new answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Andronicus made an earlier comment that

> fetch should do the job, but it's just a suggestion for hibernate, if
>   it doesn't, then that could be the result of complex mapping

So trying a different approach, I was able to achieve what I was after by constructing a DAO in this manner:

```
/** DAO to interact with EntityHistory records */
public interface EntityHistoryDao extends JpaRepository<EntityHistory, Long> {

    /** Returns EntityHistory records with IDs greater than the given ID */
    @QueryHints(value = @QueryHint(name = org.hibernate.jpa.QueryHints.HINT_FETCH_SIZE, value = "500"))
    Stream<EntityHistory> findByIdGreaterThanOrderByIdAsc(Long id);
}
```

Then to go along with that, I used the `@Transactional` tag where this method is invoked:

```
@Service
public class ScheduledExecutor {

    @Autowired
    private EntityHistoryDao entityHistoryDao;

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 05 0 * * ?")
    public void extractHistory() {      
        long lastId = 12345l;
        sendEntityHistory(lastId);
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public void sendEntityHistory(Long lastId) {
        try (Stream<EntityHistory> history = entityHistoryDao.findByIdGreaterThanOrderByIdAsc(lastId)) {
            history.forEach((record) -> {
                // Can now access all the records I want on the results
            });
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This annotation will do the trick:

```
@EntityGraph(attributePaths = { "changes" })
Stream<EntityHistory> findByIdGreaterThanOrderByIdAsc(Long id);
```

It will create a join query (the listed properties will be loaded eagerly), so all the data will be loaded in one query, so you don't even need the `@Transactional` annotation on your service method.

---

### Edit

I overlooked the `Stream` return type. (I never used Stream as return type in a repository before)
I still believe if you change the return type to `List<EntityHistory>`, then it will work.

Comment: I tested this and it's not the case.  Removing the `@Transactional` annotation on the service method, and applying the `@EntityGraph` annotation on the DAO method creates a similar issue: `InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: You're trying to execute a streaming query method without a surrounding transaction that keeps the connection open so that the Stream can actually be consumed. Make sure the code consuming the stream uses @Transactional or any other way of declaring a (read-only) transaction.`

Comment: Trying it with a `List<EntityHistory>` instead of `Stream<EntityHistory>` again results in the original error: `LazyInitializationException: Unable to perform requested lazy initialization [com.company.model.EntityHistory.changes] - no session and settings disallow loading outside the Session`